# How do I connect interact with the aws sdk via a aws profile that is not default?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

My organization uses federated access [enter link description here][1]to aws which means I need to regenerate my aws credentials every so often so hard coding them or even setting them as environmental vars are not an option.

I have found http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SharedCredentials.html#profile_name-instance_method which documents the class, but I am not really able to convert that into actual code (please forgive my ignorance I am in operations not a computer scientist).

I have tried various methods but I am at a loss.

```
rds = Aws::RDS::Resource.new(
  profile_name: 'foo'
)
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Aws::RDS::Resource initialize method this should work. However, you might have profile_name in ENV['AWS_PROFILE'] or shared_config.profile_name which is overriding @profile_name = options[:profile_name]. One way you could debug this is by using the pry gem which will allow you to see what these variables are set to inside the initialize method.

```
# bundle open 'aws-sdk-core' 
# Find File 'aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/shared_credentials.rb', line 24
# add require pry; binding.pry under the last @profile_name variable in aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/shared_credentials.rb'

def initialize(options = {})
  shared_config = Aws.shared_config
  @path = options[:path]
  @path ||= shared_config.credentials_path
  @profile_name = options[:profile_name]
  @profile_name ||= ENV['AWS_PROFILE']
  @profile_name ||= shared_config.profile_name
  require pry; binding.pry 
  if @path && @path == shared_config.credentials_path
    @credentials = shared_config.credentials(profile: @profile_name)
  else
    config = SharedConfig.new(
      credentials_path: @path,
      profile_name: @profile_name
    )
    @credentials = config.credentials(profile: @profile_name)
  end
end
```

Once you run the rds variable that you created it will trigger pry console to open up inside that method. You'll now have access to shared_config.profile_name, ENV['AWS_PROFILE', and also options.

```
pry(main)> options
         => {:profile_name=>"foo"}
           @profile_name 
         => 'foo' or whatever its set to.
           ENV['AWS_PROFILE']
         => see if it returns some value 
           shared_config.profile_name
         => see if it returns some value
```